# What Quantlib's functions are exported to Python, Excel, etc.?

Tags: quantlib

Is Quantlib's NullCalendar exported to Python? Can't see that there.

Also, in general where can I see Quantlib's functions that are exported to Python, Excel, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import QuantLib as ql
>>> cal = ql.NullCalendar()
>>> cal.isHoliday(ql.Date(1,4,2018))
False
>>>
```

There's no maintained list of what's in the wrappers, though.  For Python and the other languages exported through SWIG, you can look into the SWIG interface files in [QuantLib-SWIG/SWIG](https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib-SWIG/tree/master/SWIG).